# How do I edit PYTHONPATH?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, path, centos, pythonpath

I have edited my PYTHONPATH in the .bashrc file but now I want to edit a section of it.

1. I have a program which uses a particular source file, say libraryX
2. So I set the PYTHONPATH to

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path1/"
```

I added the above in my .bashrc file
3. source .bashrc
4. Next, I realized I had to set PYTHONPATH to path2 instead so I repeated steps 2 and 3 except I replaced path1 by path2 in the .bashrc file
5. Now, there is a conflict and since the PYTHONPATH is now

```
/path1/path2/
```

and path1 is first, it does not consider path2 which is the right path.

How do I remove path1? i.e. edit PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 2):

Reset pythonpath and re-create it from bashrc

```
unset PYTHONPATH
source ~/.bashrc
```